# Can bounding boxes be used in UNets?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, computer-vision, object-detection

I recently read a paper where the researchers used a UNet algorithm to localize/detect cyclones using a bounding box. However, my interpretation of a UNet is that it performs semantic segmentation and that bounding boxes were used in localization algorithms instead. Can someone clear this up for me?

Link to mentioned paper:https://repository.library.noaa.gov/view/noaa/31895/noaa_31895_DS1.pdf

Answer (score 1):

By a quick skimming, it seems like the network first segments the image to yes/no cyclone pixels (your semantic segmentation), then draws a bounding box of a fixed size around the center of cyclone labeled pixels. This is not part of the network's architecture, it's just a simple heuristics run after segmentation. This is kind of explained at the page 1975, and the box size is discussed elsewhere.